# Relative date filters (ending.month changed?)

Tags: upgrade

I am working with an old installation updated to 5.19.3 (Joomla) and checking it with one fresh installed. There is one difference in the table `civicrm_option_value`  field: 'value' by the realtive-date-filters.

The upgraded database has the values ending.month', 'ending_2.month', 'ending.quarter' and the new one 'ending_30.day', 'ending_60.day'and 'ending_90.day'. 
Have I had one error in a upgrade or is the difference not important?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the (default) options for relative comparisons on dates have been slightly improved (or at least, that would have been the intention). You wouldn't normally want to break a site that was making use of the old ones, so I wouldn't describe that as an upgrade error. Whether the difference is important would be up to you. If you're not using the old ones, then you could update, or even add the new ones.

You can do that with the web interface at: Administer -> System Settings -> Option Groups, and choose Date Relative Filters.

These are intended to be configurable, so the preferred behaviour for upgrades is to not break any existing configuration.

Comment: This could be a unimportant difference in the program but i dont think that you can expect that a user see this change. You can change it only directly in the database. Normally all changes in the fresh install are done in the upgrade script for old installments. To be sure that the script is not broken the program must now maintain two options, probaly just a change to describe better the results. It seems that no user had any problems with it, or not found mine post.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more details. A fresh install is never going to be the same as an upgraded install, and not all changes are worth documenting.